# Understanding Haskell lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci

Forgive my stupid question, I'm new to Haskell.

I tried in Haskell the following:

```
sum [fib n| n <- [1..], (even (fib n) && fib n < 4000000)]
```

which takes infinite time. If I leave out `n <- [1..]`, the solution comes at once.

I thought it shouldn't matter because Haskell is evaluating lazy.Did I misunderstand lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 7):

Note that

```
sum [ n | n <- [1..], n < 10 ]
```

will not terminate as well, since it will try all possible `n`s just in case one more element is found to be "less than 10" so that it is included in the sum.

By comparison,

```
sum $ takeWhile (< 10) [ n | n <- [1..] ]
```

will terminate, since `takeWhile` will discard the rest of the list as soon as an item is found not to satisfy the predicate `<10`.

Answer (score 6):

Your list comprehension of

```
sum [fib n | n <- [1..], even (fib n) && fib n < 4000000]
```

Is equivalent to the expression

```
sum $ map fib $ filter (\n -> even (fib n) && fib n < 4000000) [1..]
```

Looking at the definition of `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter predicate [] = []
filter predicate (x:xs)
    | predicate x = x : filter predicate xs
    | otherwise   =     filter predicate xs
```

we can see that it always will examine every element in the list until it reaches the end of the list.  The list being provided to filter in your expression is `[1..]`, which is infinite.  This is fine in Haskell, it just means that the filter will never finish if you force the evaluate of the entire list.  You then pass it to `map fib`, which can also handle infinite lists just fine, but what gets you is that you pass it to `sum`, which requires that there be a finite number of elements to add together.

To fix this, as @chi has pointed out, you can use `takeWhile` instead:

```
sum $ map fib $ filter (\n -> even (fib n)) $ takeWhile (\n -> fib n < 4000000) [1..]
```

Although I will note that you're applying `fib` 3 different times in this expression.  What would be best is to `map fib` first, then you don't have to apply it again:

```
sum $ filter even $ takeWhile (< 4000000) $ map fib [1..]
```